# Why Jetty asks for ProxyTo, when I have provided one

Tags: java, reverse-proxy, embedded-jetty

I have code for starting a web app in Jetty. I want to add reverse proxy handling inside the app. When I call API,

I get error `UnavailableException: Init parameter 'proxyTo' is required`.

```java
Server server = new Server(port);

WebAppContext webapp = createWebAppContext();

ServletHolder proxyServlet = new ServletHolder(ProxyServlet.Transparent.class);
proxyServlet.setInitParameter("ProxyTo", "http://attachments.dev.balcia.com:30310/api/");
proxyServlet.setInitParameter("Prefix", "/api");
webapp.addServlet(proxyServlet, "/api/attachments/*");

server.setHandler(webapp);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The init-parameter is called `proxyTo` not `ProxyTo`.

Servlet init-parameters are case sensitive.